# Logstash configuration error on Regular expression for matching pattern

Tags: regex, logstash, logstash-configuration

Can you check once the below Regualr Expression for multiple cases.

**multiple cases:**

```
Invoice_IID
InvoiceIID:
Inovoice_IID
invoice iid
invoice_iid
```

**log message is:**

```
invoice_iid 80000000-41fb-1638-cd42-ffff08d24480
```

**grok filter is:**

```
grok { 
  match => { "msg" => [iI]no*voice[_," "][iI][iI][dD]:? %{UUID:InvoiceIID}" } 
}
```

This is working perfectly in grokDebugger site like http://grokconstructor.appspot.com/do/match#result

But,when am running it's giving a configuration error (chek with --configtest.)

So please provide the correct way of writing RE ??

Comment: Maybe [`[iI]no*voice[_ ]?[iI][iI][dD]:?`](https://regex101.com/r/wT7eI3/1)? But it does not look to be a regex issue.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you the quotation marks are the problem. Try this instead

```
grok { 
  match => { "msg" => "[iI]no*voice[_, ][iI][iI][dD]:? %{UUID:InvoiceIID}" } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution for this problem.

```
grok { 
  match => { "msg" => "[iI]no*voice[_,\" \"][iI][iI][dD]:? %{UUID:InvoiceIID}" } 
}
```